# Thumbnails from video posts not working after upgrading to WP 3.4

Tags: thumbnails

I'm using Auto Featured Image plugin to generate thumbnails for my posts. After upgrading to WP 3.4 all the posts that had videos and thumbnails generated from youtube disappeared. I found another plugin called Video Thumbnails which created the thumbnails for all video posts but now the thumbnails are not showing on the home page. Does anybody know why this is happening? The below code was used for the thumbnails:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <?php
    $imgsrcparam = array(
    'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( $post->post_title )),
    'title' => trim(strip_tags( $post->post_title )),);
                    $thumbID = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, array(235,235), $imgsrcparam ); ?>
                    <a>" class="preview"><?php echo $thumbID; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your question to make answers possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a solution [there](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-auto-post-thumbnail-wordpress-34-previously-generated-thumbnails-missing-wont-generate-new-ones), though it's not perfect -it worked perfectly on one of my two sites and almost perfectly on the other...-

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.